# Is there a way for native npm packages to depend on a specific version of the V8 C++ API?

Tags: c++, node.js, v8, node-gyp, node.js-addon

Today I discovered that old versions of node-fibers and bcrypt that compile successfully on node 0.10.40 don't compile successfully on node 5.1.0.

For instance if I try to compile bcrypt 0.7.8, I get errors that must surely be due to changes in the V8 API:

```
> bcrypt@0.7.8 install /Users/andy/jcore-portal/target/device/dist/bundle/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-gyp rebuild

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:54:18: error: no member named 'Dispose' in
      'v8::Persistent<v8::Function, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function>
      >'
        callback.Dispose();
        ~~~~~~~~ ^
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:128:19: error: unknown type name 'uv_work_t'
void GenSaltAsync(uv_work_t* req) {

...
```

Clearly `bcrypt` was not able to determine that the V8 API was an incompatible version.  Nor do I see any fields in `package.json` or `node-gyp` config that would seem applicable.  Is this a bug in its build script, or is it merely impossible for packages to determine the V8 library version?

Comment: It looks like `bcrypt` has their `nan` dependency version fixed instead of using the caret so that newer (backwards compatible) versions get picked up automatically. You should consider filing an issue on their GH issue tracker and/or submitting a PR to add the caret.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#engines

You can specify the version of node that your stuff works on:

```
{
... 
  "engines" : { 
    "node" : ">=0.10.3 <0.12" 
  }
}
```